# Django aggregation issue

Tags: django, django-models

I have a little problem in connection with aggregation through Django's ORM. The sketch of my model is very simple with some custom field types (but those types are irrelevant in the problem):

**Fields types**

```
class MoneyField(models.DecimalField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        kwargs['max_digits'] = 15
        kwargs['decimal_places'] = 2
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class RevenueField(MoneyField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['validators'] = [MinValueValidator(0)]
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class WeakTextField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 200
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class NameField(WeakTextField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['unique'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class YearField(models.PositiveIntegerField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['validators'] = [
            MinValueValidator(1900),
            MaxValueValidator(2100),
        ]
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class WeakForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        kwargs['on_delete'] = models.SET_NULL
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Model entities**

```
class Company(models.Model):

    registration_number = NameField(_('Registration number')) # custom field, defined above
    name = NameField(_('Name'))
   ...
   ..
   .

class Financial(models.Model):

    financial_year = YearField(_('Financial year'))
    company = WeakForeignKey(to='Company', verbose_name=_('Company'))
    revenue = RevenueField(_('Revenue'))
   ...
   ..
   .

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('financial_year', 'company'),)
```

My goal is to compose a query with QuerySet like this:

```
SELECT financial_year, SUM(revenue) 
FROM financial
GROUP BY financial_year
```

As far as I could understand the ORM it should be done like this:

```
qs = Financial.objects.values('financial_year').annotate(Sum('revenue'))
```

however if i print out the SQL query it has an extra `"data_manager_company"."name"` field after the Group By statement:

```
SELECT 
    "data_manager_financial"."financial_year", 
    CAST(SUM("data_manager_financial"."revenue") AS NUMERIC) AS "revenue__sum"
FROM "data_manager_financial" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "data_manager_company" 
ON ("data_manager_financial"."company_id" = "data_manager_company"."id") 
GROUP BY 
    "data_manager_financial"."financial_year", 
    "data_manager_company"."name"
ORDER BY "data_manager_company"."name" 
ASC, "data_manager_financial"."financial_year" ASC
```

I'm afraid this problem is related with the unique constraint of the Financial entity. Of course the problem can be solved through raw SQL or through a separate entity for the financial year field but i dont like them. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Gallusz

Comment: What if you add `.order_by('financial_year')` at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the idea that this is more because you *annotate* every separate object. So as a result the *same* `'financial_year'` will occur *multiple* times in your query.

You can "*fold*" these years into one entry by, I know that sound strange, an **`.order_by(..)`** statement:

```
qs = Financial.objects.values(
    'financial_year'
).annotate(
    Sum('revenue')
).order_by(
    'financial_year'
)
```

So here we instruct Django to only use `'financial_year'` as a grouper, and thus `Sum(..)` over the `'revenue'` for each `'financial_year'`.

Comment: It worked like charm :) However djangos order_by / group_by is a little confusing wit SQL background. Thanks a lot!